# What is the "underlying type" in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

Recently I have stumbled upon an scalac error message complaining about two types not being the same though the "underlying type" is the same. Regardless of the error and its specifics, I'm curious about this "underlying type". What is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a singleton type `x.type` it's the type of `x`. For example, if you have `val x: Int` the underlying type of `x.type` is `Int`.

Comment: The underlying type of `x.type` is `Int`... because the actual type of `x.type` is _not_ `Int`? I'm so confused about the distinction here.

Comment: `x.type` is not `Int`. There's no "actual type of `x.type`" which could be `Int` or not.